# Creating Search in PHP get two variables at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a search bar, when i do this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%'OR qualification LIKE '%".$query."%'";
```

It gets the data out correctly, no problems, then i try to do something to get 2 data out from the database, Something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%'OR qualification LIKE '%".$query."%' OR title,location LIKE '%".$query."%'";
```

It doesnt return any results.
I would like it to get data from the database by title and Location.

Full Query Looks like this

```
<?php
//error_reporting(0);
                    require_once('inc/config.php');
                    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass, $db) or die ('Cannot connect :'.mysqli_error());
                    $query = $_GET['query'];
                    //$sql = "select * from info where title = '$title'";
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%'OR qualification LIKE '%".$query."%' OR CONCAT(title,location) LIKE '%".$query."%'";
                    mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ('Failed Query : '.mysqli_error($con));
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
                    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ) )
                    {

                        echo "<tr>
                        <td width=297 align=center>" . $row['title'] . "</td>
                        <td width=369 align=center>" . $row['location'] . "</td>
                        <td width=226 align=center>" . $row['qualification'] . "</td>
                        <td width=226 align=center>" . $row['date_posted'] . "</td>
                        <td>
                           <a href=http://www.google.de>
                           <input type=submit value=View Detail name=B4 style=font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 10pt></br></p>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
                    } 

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `OR title,location LIKE '%".$query."%'";` ?

Comment: what do u exactly mean by `2 data` .Does it mean matching 2 columns?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz, what i mean is, i want it to fetch information from the two columns. thats what i meant, sorry i missed that part.

Comment: Still not clear ?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT title, location FROM info WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%'OR qualification LIKE '%".$query."%'";

Comment: Remove `OR title,location LIKE '%".$query."%'"` from last

Comment: @PrinceKayastha, returns empty result.

Comment: the code on your snippet mentioning the whole source code has a wrong **where** clause.      TRY THIS ::: 
'
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%'OR qualification LIKE '%".$query."%' OR CONCAT(title,location) LIKE '%".$query."%'";
'

Comment: @PrinceKayastha, still returns empty results.